# I can't share SharedPreferences between BroadcastReceiver and AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

I set a preference on a BroadcastReceiver but i can't read on AppCompatActivity.
I did read some post but i can't do that it work.
The activity and the broadcastreceiver are on the same app (same package name)
On a broadcastreceiver i have this code on the method onReceive:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PROPERTIES.SHARENAME,
                context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putBoolean("runnig", true).commit();
```

and on Activity i have:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs1  =getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PROPERTIES.SHARENAME,
                        MODE_PRIVATE);

boolean corriendo= prefs1.getBoolean("running",false);
```

but the variable corriendo still false.

I tryid with context.getShared... on broadcastreceiver, using apply instead of commit,avoiding getApplicationContext() on activity and i can't do that work  .
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you made a typo:

Compare:

```
prefs.edit().putBoolean("runnig", true).commit();
boolean corriendo= prefs1.getBoolean("running",false);
```

And now just the relevant bits:

```
putBoolean("runnig", true)
getBoolean("running",false)
```

TLDR; You're reading from and writing to different keys.

Comment: OMG, you have all reason, i did check it 3 times i not found the diferences. It working now!!

Comment: No worries; stuff happens. Just as a general tip to avoid a situation like this in the future: set up a constant for your key name. Something like: `public static final String PREF_KEY_RUNNING = "running"`, and then update your puts and gets to leverage this constant: `putBoolean(PREF_KEY_RUNNING, true)` and `getBoolean(PREF_KEY_RUNNING, false)`.